# Solve the given inequality below in the body.

Tags: inequality

> $$\frac{1}{|x|-3} \le \frac 12$$

Let’s consider $|x|=y$

So $$\frac{1}{y-3}-\frac 12 \le 0$$

$$\frac{2-y+3}{y-3} \le 0$$
$$\frac{y-5}{y-3} \ge 0$$
$$y \in (-\infty , 3)\cup [5, \infty)$$
Now this is where the problem starts. I cannot figure out on how to break the modulus function, so that’s the part where I need help in. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyway, in your case, $y\ge 0$, so you should transform all this to
$$|x|<3\;\textit{ or }\; |x|\ge 5\iff -3<x<3\;\textit{ or }\; x\ge 5\;\textit{ or }\; x\le -5$$
or, as a set, the union of three intervals:
$$(-\infty,-5]\cup(-3,3)\cup[5,+\infty). $$

Answer (score 2):

The equivalences $$\lvert A\rvert< B\iff\begin{cases}B\ge 0\\ A> -B\\ A< B\end{cases}\\ \lvert A\rvert\ge B\iff B\le 0\lor \begin{cases}B> 0\\ A\le -B\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}B>0\\ A\ge B\end{cases}$$

are a good place to start from.

Comment: In your first equivalence, the inequalities should be strict.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, thank you.

Comment: Even $B$ should be positive, since $|A|\ge 0$.

Comment: @Bernard For $B=0$ the other two inequations sort it out (though you may argue that so do they when $B<0$).

Comment: There remains  that $|A|<B\Rightarrow B>0$, from a strictly logical point of view.

Comment: Anyone may squeeze as he best sees fit.

Comment: As you wish, mylord…

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|<3$, the LHS is negative and the inequation certainly holds. Now assuming $|x|>3$, we can solve the equation

$$\frac1{|x|-3}=\frac12,$$ which gives $|x|=5$. The inequation holds for $|x|\ge5$. Your resolution was right.

So the solution set is

$$(-3,3)\cup(-\infty,-5]\cup[5,\infty).$$